# "snapping" polygons together

Tags: geometry, gis, polygons

I have a set of polygons representing administrative districts. The districts were digitized by hand, and there are small spaces between polygons where the polygons should be touching. There are probably also overlapping polygons.  How can I have the polygons snap together, filling the gaps and removing overlap?

QGIS / ArcGIS or Python library solution preferred (but algorithm suggestions welcome)

Comment: This is a gis.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: I have asked this question at gis.stackexchange.com.  There doesn't seem to be a tool to do this, so I'm also looking for a computational geometry approach to implement myself.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Sorry if my first answer was a bit impolite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old school ArcInfo had a "clean" function - I think they did the same thing in geoprocessing if you use a geodb. In that function you set a tolerance for snapping lines and points together. The clean gets rid of all those slivers (the technical term for what you are talking about).

For Qgis:

This thread should be of some help to you
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3126

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is 6 months old but ayway, you can use the [Integrate tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002s000000) in ArcGIS which should do what you want.

Comment: great solution because it doesn't require a special license and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tool in the ArcGIS world called: [geometry repair](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=repair_geometry_%28data_management%29). You can use the python API.

Comment: But this tool repairs corrupted files, fixing invalid geometry in single features. It does not help with the problem in the question.