# Merging features to one just gives back a feature with braking lines within

Tags: merge, polygon, qgis, feature-selection

I have a similar question to this one: ["snapping" polygons together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345343/snapping-polygons-together)

I have drawn let's say **3 areas**. The **1.** is **overlapping with** the **2.** and the **2.** is **overlapping with** the **3.**

I made sure that I was using the snapping tool and the outer lines are matching each other. That is all fine. But now I want them to be just one feature. So I marked the 3 features and hit "**Merge Selected Features**". It seemed to work, but there is still the line between them.

Then I gave "**Dissolve**" a try but it had the same result.

So I played around but did not find any way to handle that. What I more would like to have would be that I can join points. IS there maybe something like merge points? Any ideas are welcome.

Here a picture with the vertical unwanted line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmx4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overally merging features is working. But there is a big issue when one features has **issues**.

All you need to do is checking the to be merged features. **Solve** any **issue** like **multiple points** or **intersections**. Now try merging them again and it should work. At least for myself it did.

Another issue could be QGIS. Here it helps a simple **restart** of **QGIS**.